# How to select 2 fields in where clause

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere

I want to match 2 pair of fields in where clause

```
select * from A where (x,y) in (select u,v from B)
```

Can some one guide me

Answer (score 1):

You want to write this - which is valid SQL by the way - just not implemented in Sybase:

```
select *
from A
where (x,y) in (select u,v from B) ;
```

The easiest way is to rewrite is by using an `EXISTS` correlated subquery instead:

```
select * 
from A 
where exists
      (select 1 from B
       where A.x = B.u
         and A.y = B.v
      ) ;
```